# C# use of unassigned variable

Tags: c#

I have the following C# setup:

```
DateTime DOB;
DateTime.TryParse(dicGuarantor["DateOfBirth"].ToString(), out DOB);
....
DateOfBirth = DOB;
```

My question relates to the scenario where the `TryParse` fails.

As far as I understand, the variable

`DateTime DOB`

would remain unassigned, meaning that in this scenario, when the code reaches the line:

```
DateOfBirth = DOB;
```

It will give an error relating to using an unassigned variable.

However, this does not seem to happen in my code, no errors occur and the page displays as expected.

I am concerned that there is really an error here, and I am not seeing it, and that further down the line the code will break because of it.

Can anyone clarify - there does not seem to be much online that answers this question.

As a note, I tried:

```
DateTime DOB = null;
```

On the declaration, but this says:

> 'Cannot convert null to 'System.DateTime' becasuse it is a
>   non-nullavle value type'

EDIT:

Given the answers below, I will first add the declaration of the variable `DateOfBirth` to the question:

```
public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

Which means this is a `nullable DateTime Obeject`

Now, assuming the `TryParse` fails, the variable it will assign:

`DOB = DateTime.MinValue;`

and therefore:

```
DateOfBirth = DateTime.MinValue;
```

Now somewhere else in the code,

I have the following:

```
if (DateOfBirth.HasValue)
...
```

From running the code, it seems that this will return false when `DateOfBirth` has been assigned the value `DateTime.MinValue`

Is this as expected?

Comment: You can't set DOB=null, if you need to do so, you need to declare it as nullable

Comment: What is the type of the value stored in `dicGuarantor["DateOfBirth"]`? If it already is a DateTime, just cast: `DOB = (DateTime)dicGuarantor["DateOfBirth"];`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`out` parameter must be assigned by method, no matter what it returns, so `TryParse` will assign something to `value` before returning `false`. Quoting from the C# specification:

> Within a method, just like a local variable, an output parameter is initially considered unassigned and must be definitely assigned before its value is used.
>
> Every output parameter of a method must be definitely assigned before the method returns.

If you look at the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,635a8f27ec7b1ec2,references), it will be assigned to `DateTime.MinValue` before doing anything else:

```
internal static bool TryParse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles, out DateTime result) {
    result = DateTime.MinValue;
    DateTimeResult resultData = new DateTimeResult();       // The buffer to store the parsing result.
    resultData.Init();
    if (TryParse(s, dtfi, styles, ref resultData)) {
        result = resultData.parsedDate;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `HasValue` will return `true` in that case. `MinValue` is a value. There is no `TryParse` overload that takes `Nullable<DateTime>`.

Comment: to confirm, if the variable has the value DateTime.Minvalue, you would expect it to return false for the statement if (DateOfBirth.HasValue)

Comment: No, it will return `true`. Sorry, misunderstoof your comment. Updated mine to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

No, when you call a method with an "out" parameter, the method has to asign a vaule to it:

> Although variables passed as out arguments do not have to be
>   initialized before being passed, the called method is required to
>   assign a value before the method returns.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx)

You can't even compile this:

```
public void Foo(out DateTime value)
{
}
```

> CS0177 The out parameter 'value' must be assigned to before control
>   leaves the current method

Answer (score 2):

Please the [docs of this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e(v=vs.110).aspx). It says that when TryParse fails, it assigns `DateTime.MinValue` to your out variable so you cannot expect it to be unassigned after calling `TryParse` method. it will contain some value. if value is valid or not depends upon the returned result of `TryParse`. if it returns true, the `out` parameter will have converted date otherwise, it will have `DateTime.MinValue` as its value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this :

```
if(!DateTime.TryParse(dicGuarantor["DateOfBirth"].ToString(), out DOB))
{
    DOB = new DateTime()
}
```

If it fail while try to parse it make new DateTime object which will be empty

Or use DateTime as nullable `DataTime?`

Comment: No need to do this, the DOB is always definitely assigned (that is a requirement of using "out")

Comment: Yes but this allow to do whatever we want if tare fail this time i use new object initialize as example